# OpenGl Rotation around point

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

My problem is that I need to rotate a white square around the center of the far left end, and no matter what I try, I cannot seem to do it.

I need to rotate an object around `radius`, which is `radius` far from the position (`getPosition().x/y`), which i have already translated to. I need to rotate it r degrees. If it matters, I am using an orthographic (`glOrtho`) projection.

So far this what I tried:

```
//Try 1
glRotatef(r, 0, 0, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(radius, radius, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
//draw here...

//Try 2
glTranslatef(-radius, -radius, 0);
glRotatef(r, 0, 0, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(radius, radius, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
//draw here...

//Try 3
glTranslatef(radius + getPosition().x, radius + getPosition().y, 0);
glRotatef(r, 0, 0, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(radius, radius, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
//draw here...
```

I have tried Googling and searching on StackOverflow **numerous** times, with no luck. Two of these "solutions" came from answers found on StackOverflow itself.

All of these attempts rotate around the origin. I have also tried numerous other more nonsensical combinations, to no avail. If it matters, a little bit before this code, I translate the matrix (and don't pop it back out). I don't think this is the problem, as popping the matrix and pushing a new one back on right before any of these attempts does not fix the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `glTranslatef` takes three arguments, not two. Not sure if that's at typo.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes thats a typo will fix now

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo So i have tried several other things, including isolating some opengl code and trying all sorts of translations, but no matter what i do, the object wont rotate around a point. In fact, it wont even rotate around __any__ point, period, only around the origin.

Comment: Your second try should work for rotating around a point. I suspect that you're calling `glLoadIdentity` somewhere after rotating, but without more code, I can't be sure.

Comment: By "rotate a white square around the center of the far left end" do you mean around the center of one of the sides?

Comment: @MtRoad yes that is what I meant. However I have figured it out. See my answer. Thanks for interest though! This problem was REALLY bothering me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution:

```
glTranslatef(radius + getPosition().x, radius + getPosition().y, 0);
glRotatef(r, 0, 0, 1.0f);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
```

It turns out you ***dont*** have to translate after the rotation, which is was several sources suggested.